# Sequelize polymorphic many to many - `add` mixin not working

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, polymorphic-associations

I have a many-to-many polymorphic association setup for customer surveys. The issue that I have run into is when using the `add` mixin on the model instance of `Survey`. If the joining table already has an item with the `surveyed` field equal to the `id` of the new surveyable, it gets overwritten.

`survey` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Customer Survey' |

`scheduled_sessions` table:

| id | appointment_data |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | { "someData" : [] } |

`service_provider` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Joe Doe |

`survey_surveyable` table:

| survey | surveyable | surveyed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | serviceProvider | 10 |

When I `add` a scheduled session that happens to have the same id as a service provider, the join table row is overwritten:

```js
const surveyInstance = await DB.Survey.findByPk(1);
const scheduledSessionInstance = await DB.ScheduledSession.findByPk(10);

surveyInstance.addScheduledSession(
  scheduledSessionInstance,
  { through: { surveyable: "scheduledSession" } }
);

return surveyInstance.save();
```

This is the SQL queries that sequelize runs:

```sql
SELECT "id", "name"
  FROM "surveys" AS "Survey"
  WHERE "Survey"."id" = 1;

SELECT "id", "appointment_data" AS "appointmentData"
  FROM "scheduled_sessions" AS "ScheduledSession"
  WHERE "ScheduledSession"."id" = 10;

SELECT "survey", "surveyable", "surveyed"
  FROM "survey_surveyable" AS "SurveySurveyable"
  WHERE
    "SurveySurveyable"."survey" = 1 AND
    "SurveySurveyable"."surveyed" IN (10);

UPDATE "survey_surveyable"
  SET "surveyable"=$1
  WHERE
    "survey" = $2 AND
    "surveyed" = $3
```

Since both the scheduled session and the service provider have `id=10`, the service provider row in the join table is overwritten resulting in:

`survey_surveyable` table:

| survey | surveyable | surveyed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | scheduledSession | 10 |

where it should have been:

`survey_surveyable` table:

| survey | surveyable | surveyed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | serviceProvider | 10 |
| 1 | scheduledSession | 10 |

Is this a sequelize issue, or am I using the `add` mixin incorrectly?

### My models:

Survey.js:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Survey extends sequelize.Sequelize.Model {};

  Survey.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: "surveys",
      sequelize
    }
  );

  Survey.associate = (models) => {
    Survey.belongsToMany(models.ScheduledSession, {
      through: {
        model: models.SurveySurveyable,
        unique: false
      },
      foreignKey: "survey",
      constraints: false
    });
  };

  return Survey;
};
```

ScheduledSession.js:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class ScheduledSession extends sequelize.Sequelize.Model {};

  ScheduledSession.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      }
      appointmentData: {
        type: DataTypes.JSONB,
        allowNull: false,
        field: "appointment_data"
      }
    },
    {
      paranoid: true,
      tableName: "scheduled_sessions",
      sequelize
    }
  );

  ScheduledSession.associate = (models) => {
    ScheduledSession.belongsToMany(models.Survey, {
      through: {
        model: models.SurveySurveyable,
        unique: false,
        scope: {
          surveyable: "scheduledSession"
        }
      },
      foreignKey: "surveyed",
      constraints: false
    });
  };

  return ScheduledSession;
};
```

ServiceProvider.js:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class ServiceProvider extends sequelize.Sequelize.Model {};

  ServiceProvider.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      }
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      paranoid: true,
      tableName: "service_provider",
      sequelize
    }
  );

  ServiceProvider.associate = (models) => {
    ServiceProvider.belongsToMany(models.Survey, {
      through: {
        model: models.SurveySurveyable,
        unique: false,
        scope: {
          surveyable: "serviceProvider"
        }
      },
      foreignKey: "surveyed",
      constraints: false
    });
  };

  return ServiceProvider;
```

SurveySurveyable.js:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class SurveySurveyable extends sequelize.Sequelize.Model {};

  SurveySurveyable.init(
    {
      survey: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      surveyable: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
      },
      surveyed: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        constraints: false
      }
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: "survey_surveyable",
      sequelize,
      freezeTableName: true
    }
  );

  return SurveySurveyable;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Survey`'s mixin but missing `scope` in `Survey`'s association.

```
Survey.associate = (models) => {
  Survey.belongsToMany(models.ScheduledSession, {
    through: {
      model: models.SurveySurveyable,
      unique: false,
      scope: {                           // This is missing
        surveyable: "scheduledSession"
      }
    },
    foreignKey: "survey",
    constraints: false
  });
};
```

Comment: You are my hero! This was missing from the sequelize docs for some reason.